# Can run SSIS package on Ad-Hoc Server to insert result to another server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have a SSIS package for getting data  from a webservice and insert to the SQL Server(using OLEDB connection with sql user).

but I would like to add the agent job on SQL Ad-hoc server by using a filesystem package source.

So, the job agent will execute on SQL Ad-Hoc Server but inside a package will getting data from a webservice and import to another server.

Is it impossible to do that?
I try this solution but found error about
"Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D. 
   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
   Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user "

and

Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B 
"Key not valid for use in specified state."

but I can set a CREDENTIAL across a server ><

Could someone please help me with this problem

Thank you

Comment: It is certainly possible, provided all the permissions are in place.  I see you want to run the package from the file system. Why?  SSISDB is made for that purpose and allows easy configuration of connection info.  To do it with DTEXEC, you'll need to provide the connection string on the commandline, which could be a security risk.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me,
actually I prefer to use the SSISDB but my security team they not allow me to create the SSISDB on the server  they allow a filesystem source only >.<"

So, If I would like to use a filesystem I must insert a password in a connection string in a jop properties like this

"Data Source=WIN-ABCD;User ID=sa; Password=P@ssw0rd; Initial Catalog=gg;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;" right?

so it could be a security risk right? O_o

Comment: I don't understand, when I already save sql user password in a OLEDB in visual studio in my package why the package doesn't remember sql password?

Comment: It depends on your "sensitive information" setting when you deploy the package.

Comment: Can you escalate the issue caused by your security team?  Why do they think the file system is more secure, for example?  Seems counter-intuitive to me.